# How to bind one item from list

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

How to bind one(whole) item from list?
I need whole object in foreground color converter, not only one field.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontWeight="Bold"Foreground="{Binding }, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter ={StaticResource CheckToleranceColorConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I resolve this issue. Only the sot sign in binding it's enought.

```
Foreground="{Binding ., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter ={StaticResource CheckToleranceColorConverter}}"
```